# What is the keyboard shortcut to jump to a page number in the firefox pdf viewer?

Tags: firefox, pdf, shortcuts

I'd like to know the keyboard shortcut to select the page navigation field in the firefox pdf viewer, so I can jump to a desired page.

I'm using Firefox 27.0.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I thought that it was ctrl-alt-g, but that does not seem to be working for me - also running Firefox 27.0.1 on a linux system.  Perhaps that shortcut key has been removed?

Comment: Not sure about Ubuntu, but does [Meta-Alt-g](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-shortcuts) work??

Comment: Not too sure which key Meta is (I tried the right-alt, esc, and windows keys), but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: It is usually mapped to the Windows logo key (the left side). [What are the meta, super, and hyper keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys)

Comment: Hmm I mapped meta to the windows key and logged out, but it's still not working.

Comment: What happens in Firefox [Safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) ... try both the shortcuts...